# Nginx wildcard subdomains with PHP enabled

Tags: nginx

I'm triyng to set up Nginx as a staging server for a few different projects using Laravel/PHP. The idea is that under `/var/www` I will have a varying number of subdirectories, each accessed in the `subdomain.example.com` format.

Consider this very simple Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;
        root /var/www/$1;
}
```

I have my directory structure set up as:

```
/var/www
    /subdomain1
    /subdomain2
    /subdomain3
```

If I access `subdomain1.example.com` , `subdomain2.example.com` or `subdomain3.example.com` then the `index.html` file in the relevant subdirectory is served. All perfect so far.

The problem comes when I try to make this work with PHP files. To begin with, I change the index directive to `index index.php` and then I add the following within the `server` directive:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Nginx accepts this configuration without any problems. However, if I try to access `subdomain1.example.com` then I get a 404 error from Nginx but there is nothing in the error log whatsoever.

If I change the try_files directive to `try_files $uri /subdomain1/index.php =404;` then it executes the `index.php` file in the `subdomain1` directory properly but this obviously defeats the purpose because I want it to work as a wildcard. The problem is that I don't have access to the $1 variable from the parent directive within the location directive.

I feel like I must be missing something quite obvious here. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have seen this before where `root` has a late binding and numeric captures go out of scope. Try using a named capture. Something like:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;
    root /var/www/$subdomain;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        ...
    }
}
```